# C++ .NET equivalent to java public static void main()?

Tags: java, .net, c++, equivalent

In java I can simply test classes directly with

```
public static void main()
```

I then just add quick code and under Eclipse "Run" the class. Is there anything similar in C++ .NET ?

Right now I have to create an empty project, reference the correct headers then set that project as start up project.

Answer (score 2):

[Unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). There's also the [object test bench](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3775d98(VS.80).aspx) if you're using VS.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in C# so I don't know if this will react any differently, but I set up an empty "test" class with the main method and then set the project to startup with that class file. You shouldn't have to create the file in a separate project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with Eclipse but if you're just looking to run your objects in the IDE do the following.

Open up the Immediate window and just call whatever function you want.  This will start execute the code you type.  You will likely have to qualify the name.  Ex: ClassLibrary1.MyClass.SomeMethod()

Answer (score 1):

I like using [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/default.aspx) for this. It allows you to execute any public method by rightclicking on the header and selecting "Run test".

I like making

```
public static void Test()
```

methods on dialog- and form-classes to use with this feature.

It supports C++/CLI, so if that is what you mean by C++.NET, it should work for you.

**Edit:** You should only do that for things that are not automatically testable - such as pure GUI classes. Otherwise I agree with the other commenters: use a unit test framework.